# How do I find the closed form of this integral $\int_0^2\frac{\ln x}{x^3-2x+4}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, partial-fractions

How do I find the closed form of this integral:
$$I=\int_0^2\frac{\ln x}{x^3-2x+4}dx$$
First, I have a partial fraction of it:
$$\frac{1}{x^3-2x+4}=\frac{1}{(x+2)(x^2-2x+2)}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2-2x+2}$$
$$A=\frac{1}{(x^3-2x+4)'}|_{x=-2}=\frac{1}{(3x^2-2)}|_{x=-2}=\frac{1}{10}$$
$$Bx+C=\frac{1}{x+2}|_{x^2-2x=-2}=\frac{1}{(x+2)}\frac{(x-4)}{(x-4)}|_{x^2-2x=-2}=$$
$$=\frac{(x-4)}{(x^2-2x-8)}|_{x^2-2x=-2}=\frac{(x-4)}{(-2-8)}|_{x^2-2x=-2}=-\frac{1}{10}(x-4)$$
Thus:
$$\frac{1}{x^3-2x+4}=\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{x-4}{x^2-2x+2}\right)$$
$$I=\frac{1}{10}\left(\int_0^2\frac{\ln x}{x+2}dx-\int_0^2\frac{(x-4)\ln x}{x^2-2x+2}dx\right)$$
What should I do next?

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives: $$\frac{1}{480} (-144 C - 7 \pi^2 + 48 \log^2(2) + 36 \pi\log(2))$$ where $C$ is Catalan's constant. I think you'll need more high powered tools than partial fractions to get that result. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor,by parts，will there's a loop,how can you do next step?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews,tank's for your closed form,It looks complicated.

Comment: I also want to point out that this integral is improper, since your bounds contain a pole of the integrand.

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor,I see, that the logarithm contains a pole, but it is still convergent.

Comment: What pole?  The only real pole is at $-2$.  The logarithm has a branch point, not a pole, at $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael,Oh,sorry, I got it wrong. The logarithm is the branch point,but -2 not within the integral range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^2\frac{\ln x}{x^3-2x+4}\,dx$

$\begin{align}I=\frac{1}{10}\int_0^2 \frac{\ln x}{2+x}\,dx+\frac{4}{10}\int_0^2 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-2x+2}\,dx-\frac{1}{10}\int_0^2 \frac{x\ln x}{x^2-2x+2}\,dx\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
A&:=\int_0^2 \frac{\ln x}{2+x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2 \frac{\ln x}{1+\frac{x}{2}}\,dx\\
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=\frac{x}{2}$,

$\begin{align}
A&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(2y)}{1+y}\,dy\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln 2}{1+y}\,dy+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{1+y}\,dy\\
&=\ln 2\Big[\ln(1+y)\Big]_0^1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\\
&=\boxed{\ln^2 2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}}
\end{align}$

It is well-known that,

$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{1+y}\,dy=-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\end{align}$

and,

$\displaystyle \zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

$\begin{align}B&:=\int_0^2 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-2x+2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^2\frac{\ln x}{(x-1)^2+1}\,dx
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $y=x-1$,

$\begin{align}B&=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy\\
&=\int_{-1}^0\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy+\int_{0}^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $x=-y$ in the first integral,

$\begin{align}B&=\int_{0}^1\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y^2+1}\,dy+\int_{0}^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy\\
\end{align}$

In the first integral perform the change of variable $\displaystyle x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$

$\begin{align}B&=\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\right)+\int_{0}^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\,dy\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}}
\end{align}$

It is well-known that,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx=-\text{G}$

$\begin{align}C&:=\int_0^2 \frac{x\ln x}{x^2-2x+2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^2\frac{x\ln x}{(x-1)^2+1}\,dx
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $y=x-1$,

$\begin{align}C&=\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1+y)\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy\\
&=B+\int_{-1}^1\frac{y\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}+\int_{-1}^0\frac{y\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy+\int_{0}^1\frac{y\ln(1+y)}{y^2+1}\,dy
\end{align}$

In the first integral perform the change of variable $x=-y$,

$\begin{align}C&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}-\int_{0}^1\frac{x\ln(1-x)}{x^2+1}\,dx+\int_{0}^1\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{x^2+1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}+\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$,

$\begin{align}C&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}+\int_0^1 \frac{(x-1)\ln x}{x^3+x^2+x+1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}+\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{2x\ln(x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
\end{align}$

In the first integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,

$\begin{align}C&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}-\frac{3}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-\text{G}+\frac{1}{16}\pi^2}
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$\boxed{\displaystyle I=\frac{1}{10}\ln^2 2+\frac{3}{40}\pi\ln 2-\frac{3}{10}\text{G}-\frac{7}{480}\pi^2}$

Comment: ,thank you very much,pretty answer, I'll say, there's elementary solution.

Comment: This is beautiful answer ! Thanks for providing it. Cheers. May I ask : where are you in France ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm from suburbs of Paris. Je ne connais pas Pau ;)

Comment: Thank you all， for helping me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I have applied the following rule, if the result doesn't contain any polylog then probably an elementary computation can be performed.

Comment: @FDP The 31 line there, x, y mixed up.

Comment: Thanks. Problem Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

*Just for your curiosity.*

If you enjoy special functions of complex arguments, the antiderivative can be computed.

$$\frac 1 {x^3-2x+4}=\frac{\frac1{10}}{
   x+2}-\frac{\frac{1}{20}-\frac{3 i}{20}}{x-(1-i)}-\frac{\frac{1}{20}+\frac{3 i}{20}}{x-(1+i)}$$ which makes that we are left with integrals $$I_a=\int \frac{\log(x)}{x-a}\,dx=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+\log (x) \log \left(1-\frac{x}{a}\right)$$ where appears the polylogarithm function.

This would lead to the result  Thomas Andrews gave in a comment.

Comment: ,Thank you for your suggest, but I don't know these complicated tools. do you have a real method?

Comment: @JamesJ. This is why I wrote the first line ! But, beside this approach, I must confess my ignorance. Cheers.

Comment: The first integral can use the formula as above:$\int_0^2\ln x/(x+2)dx=Li _2(-x/2)|_0^2+\ln x\ln (1+x/2)|_0^2=\ln^2 2-\pi ^2/12$

Comment: @JamesJ. This is correct for sure

Answer (score 1):

To address your question of how to handle loops when integrating by parts, let $I=\int e^x\sin x \ dx$. Both functions are transcendental. We'll try using $u_1=e^x$ and $dv_1=\sin x \ dx$. These give $du_1=e^x \ dx$ and $v_1=-\cos x$. Thus, $$I=-e^x\cos x+\int e^x\cos x \ dx.$$
Now we have another integral. We'll try by parts again, and it's important we keep the same arrangement as last time (i.e. we need $u_2=du_1$ and $dv_2=v_1$; in this case we used exponential as $u$ and trigonometric as $v$, though we could have dove it the other way as long as we were consistent) otherwise we will just undo our last step. So, $u_2=e^x$ and $dv_2=\cos x \ dx$. These give $du_2=e^x \ dx$ and $v_2=\sin x$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
I&=-e^x\cos x+e^x\sin x-\int e^x\sin x \ dx \\
&=e^x(\sin x-\cos x)-I \\
2I&=e^x(\sin x-\cos x) \\
I&=\frac{1}{2}e^x(\sin x-\cos x).
\end{align}
$$
The important step is realising that when you get back to where you started, you can perform algebra to solve for your result.

That said, I do not guarantee this is what's needed here, just thought it might be worth a try and then you asked. So here you go.

Comment: And yes, I'm ignoring the constant of integration.

Comment: ,My meaning is this:$\int \ln x/(x+2)dx=\int \ln xd\ln (x+2)=\ln x\ln (x+2)-\int \ln(x+2)/xdx$

Comment: That's one step of integration by parts. See if you get anything helpful if you do another (you might not, but I'm at a loss of what else to try at the moment).

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried switching your functions? I.e. using the logarithm for u and the rational function for dv?

Comment: Your meaning:$\int \ln x/(x+2)dx=\int d(x\ln x-x)/(x+2)=(x\ln x-x)/(x+2)-\int (x\ln x-x)d(1/(x+2))$?Wouldn't it be more complicated then?

Comment: Yes, I did mean that (though I just realised I said it backwards). It probably would; I was just wondering if you'd tried it.

Comment: I've tried everything in 2 directions. It's really a loop.