# How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^2 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt {x^2-2x+2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, polylogarithm

Yesterday's [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421136/how-do-i-find-the-closed-form-of-this-integral-int-02-frac-ln-xx3-2x4dx) may be too difficult, I think the following integral should not be difficult.
$$I=\int_0^2 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt {x^2-2x+2}}dx=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{\sqrt {x^2+1}}dx=\int_{-1}^1\ln(x+1)d(\ln (x+\sqrt {x^2+1}))$$
$$=\ln (x+1)\ln (x+\sqrt {x^2+1})|_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1\frac{\ln (x+\sqrt {x^2+1})}{(x+1)}dx=......$$
So far, I don't know what to do, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this integral is far too difficult - Wolfram Alpha says that the integral is: (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=indefinite+integral+of+ln+x+%2F+sqrt(x%5E2-2x%2B2))

Comment: @TobyMak,Wow,the result is too complicated,we are here only for definite integrals, and perhaps the integrand has no primitive function.

Comment: Btw, it is irrelevant what you asked yesterday, you should refrain from mentioning it. Just focus on your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sqrt {{x^2} - 2x + 2}  = x + t$, then we have
$$I=\int_0^2 {\frac{{\ln x}}{{\sqrt {{x^2} - 2x + 2} }}}  = \int_{\sqrt 2  - 2}^{\sqrt 2 } {\ln \left( {\frac{{2 - {t^2}}}{{2(t + 1)}}} \right)\frac{1}{{1 + t}}dt} $$
This integral can be broken down into pieces of the form $\int \frac{\ln x}{x+a} dx$, which can be evaluated by dilogarithm. The final result being
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Li}{Li}
I=\frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}} - \frac{9\ln ^22}{8} + \frac{3}{2}\ln (1 + \sqrt 2 )\ln 2 - \frac{1}{2}{\ln ^2}(1 + \sqrt 2 ) - \Li_2\left( {2\sqrt 2  - 2} \right) - \Li_2\left( {\frac{{2 - \sqrt 2 }}{4}} \right)$$

Comment: ,Thank you for your answer,the result is much more complicated than that one yesterday's integral ,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421136/how-do-i-find-the-closed-form-of-this-integral-int-02-frac-ln-xx3-2x4dx

Answer (score 2):

I propose a new formula with just one dilogarithm:

$I=-29\cdot\pi^2\cdot\frac{1}{24}-3\ln(1+\sqrt{2})^2-10*Li_2(-\sqrt{2}-1)+\frac12\ln(2)^2-2\ln(2+\sqrt{2})^2$